# Good design pattern for Displaying/Hiding swing components at runtime based on some business logic

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I tried to find a similar query but could not hence iam posting this.
I am working on a swing application which has a GUI made up of a number of components like JButton, JCombobox etc.

I have an important business case in which i have the following situation

1. A common set of components should be visible at all times
2. The set of components which are not applicable to a certain scenario should be hidden
3. The set of components which are applicable should be displayed in addition to what is common
4. There is a requirement that i would have to redo this application in JavaFX and therefore it would be great to have a way to make this code independent of the Swing technology.

Approach #1 : Have seperate methods in the GUI classes to hide/unhide the components and let the view/controller take care of it based on the scenario. This however is dependent on the view and would have to be written from scratch once i move to JavaFX

Approach #2 : Have a ruleset defined which would essentially contain a name of the attributes of the class which can be hidden and let a common piece of code hide/unhide it in someway by leveraging reflection. This would be independent of the type of view technology in use. 
However the usage of reflection always raises eyebrows during code reviews and since the recommended practice is to try to avoid it therefore its a bit difficult to convince people about it.

What can be a good approach to use in this case in terms of complexity vs code reuse vs effort involved?
Also is there a design pattern which could be helpful in this scenario?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: *"There is a requirement that i would have to redo this application in JavaFX and therefore.."* ..it has pretty much nothing to do with Swing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : In case i decide to use the first approach i would have re-write the code to hiding the component which is what i am referring to. For ex comp1.setVisible(false) would have to be re-written for all such components

Comment: If it's Swing use `Action` objects and disable them if not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use interfaces, Luke. Define your own extensions or (better) wrappers for the swing components you use and provide common operations which you can also implement using the JavaFX. So you can implement common operation to make the parts of your GUI visible/invisible. Additionally you should group your components in logical parts and provide technology-independent sub-controllers/sub-models for these groups. The corresponding view should have a method to make itself (in)visible.

For Swing: if you want to make a part of your GUI (view) invisible, you should use the [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) (one card with your components and another with a blank panel). The `setVisible` method can cause layout issues.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce complexity and achieve code re-usability, using an XML file to define the layout rather than doing hardcode is better. I suggest you using SwiXML to facilitate Java Swing construction. See detail at http://www.swixml.org/

Comment: How would that solve the problem as the logic would have to be written some place regardless of how i construct the view.

Comment: After you build View by SwiXML, you could utilize SwiXML to recall built components. For my practice, I use Spring to create Listener as beans to link components and listeners together.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, I used:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

With a backing `HashMap<Long,JPanel>` where the `Long` is used to differentiate between the `JPanel`s. Then, when a selection is made, I do:

```
mainPanel.remove(oldPanel);
mainPanel.add(newPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The HashMap maintains a reference to my components so they're not garbage collected, and this avoids issues that using `setVisible` can create.